# IOS Filesystem security

Tags: ios, security, ios6

I have some discussing with agencies about the Apple Filesystem Encryption. The app itself is always running in a sandbox and also by default the filesystem is encrypted. I always advice to use sqlcipher, to place files in the cache folder so they won't backups by iTunes and using a strong password. How hard is it to crack the Apple file system.

How easy/hard is it to access the apple filesystem and to crack the password?

Comment: Very easy if you have access to the device, regardless of passcode, the phone can be jailbroken and arbitrary scripts run at start-up.  This is a very complex issue and can't just be summarised. and I suggest you do some reading, I recommend 'Hacking and Securing iOS Applications' by O'Reilly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you look at [iphone-dataprotection](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-dataprotection/). They have a list of detailed notes about iOS protected files, how it's done in hardware, and some of the potential vulnerabilities.

The first two that caught my eye:

- [iOS Security](http://images.apple.com/ipad/business/docs/iOS_Security_May12.pdf)
- [iPhone data protection in depth](http://conference.hitb.org/hitbsecconf2011ams/materials/D2T2%20-%20Jean-Baptiste%20Be%CC%81drune%20&%20Jean%20Sigwald%20-%20iPhone%20Data%20Protection%20in%20Depth.pdf)